# Creating labels for certain sequences in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sample DF:

```
id seq 
1  3
1  2
1  1
1  0
1  2
1  1
1  0
1  3
1  2
1  1
1  0
```

This is how i'd like the same dataframe to look:

```
id seq seq_num
1  3   0
1  2   0
1  1   0
1  0   0
1  2   1
1  1   1
1  0   1
1  3   2
1  2   2
1  1   2
1  0   2
```

Essentially, I'd like the `seq_num` to change every time 0 is shown in `seq`. Also `seq_num` should continue to increase.

I'm really not quite sure how to start here. My pandas knowledge is failing me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is seq num also a panda dataframe?

Comment: What is `seq_num` ? Is it a seperate `df` ? If not, what is the logic for generating the `seq_num` ?

Comment: `seq_num` is a column in the original dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, `groupby().cumsum()`:

```
df['seq_num'] = (df.seq.diff().gt(0)
   .groupby(df['id'])
   .cumsum()
)
```

OUtput:

```
    id  seq  seq_num
0    1    3      0.0
1    1    2      0.0
2    1    1      0.0
3    1    0      0.0
4    1    2      1.0
5    1    1      1.0
6    1    0      1.0
7    1    3      2.0
8    1    2      2.0
9    1    1      2.0
10   1    0      2.0
```

If you don't care about sequence within different `id`'s, you can drop `.groupby()`.